# Excel - count days between two dates per year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the number of days per year between two dates.

The results should look somehow like the following picture

[image: Example]

The range between the 2 dates in the 2021 year has 301 days and in the 2022 year has 94 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in C2 and copy over:

```
=MIN(DATE(C1,12,31),$B$2)-MAX(DATE(C1,1,1),$A$2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely easy to understand but what you don't know is in plain sight: Excel represents dates as integer numbers where Jan 1, 1900 is the first day (= 1) and all days from then till now have a unique number. Today is 44261. Tomorrow will be 44262.

Therefore the difference between dates equals [End date] - [Start date], where only one of these two dates is included in the count. [Tomorrow]-[Today] = 1, not 2.

When a worksheet cell is formatted as `General` Excel will automatically change that format to whatever Excel thinks you have probably entered. If you enter what Excel recognizes as a date the cell format will be changed to `Date` and if the way you entered the date was by function, such as `=TODAY()` the cell will display "6/3/2021" using the date format specified in your Windows International settings.

But if you manually change the cell format back to `General` or `Number` the display will change to 44262. That's the way you can test if your cell contains a "true" date, with which you can do calculations, or a "fake" date, which is just a text string which is nice to look at but otherwise useless.